# Owin UseStaticFiles not respecting RequestPath

Tags: owin

**EDIT: NOTE: This appears to be fixed in later versions of the Owin StaticFiles middleware, so if you have this probem, simply upgrade **

My OWIN configuration has this:-

```
   string root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   var staticFilesOptions = new StaticFileOptions();
   staticFilesOptions.RequestPath = new PathString("/foo");
   staticFilesOptions.FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(Path.Combine(root, "web"));
   app.UseStaticFiles(staticFilesOptions);
```

When I hit `/foo/app/app.js` I get a 404 error, when I hit `/web/app/app.js` the file is returned.

How is `RequestPath` meant to work in conjunction with `PhysicalFileSystem`?

Comment: You could try the OWIN Framework implementation of StaticFiles which I am sure does not have this problem.

Answer (score 10):

I tested this code snippet and it works for me from [this sample project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/StaticFilesSample/Startup.cs).

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    RequestPath = new PathString("/foo"),
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\web"),
});
```

Make sure you have this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yup, this appears to be fixed in the latest OWIN nuget packages.

Comment: @IanMercer, I'm using version 2.1.0, the latest stable release, which came out last January.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Acording to the answer of @Rafael [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647780/1896897). Add the following configuration to **Web.config** then it resolves my issue:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="StaticFile"/>
  <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this help the other people!

Answer (score 0):

`RequestPath` you define a virtual path for your static resources used in requests, see this as a route to your static files.

Using `PhysicalFileSystem` you define the path for the static file lookup.

So, if there is a request for what you've defined in `RequestPath` the path-part is translated to the directory on your harddisk.

In your case you should receive the status code of 404 for `web/app.js` (as this is your directory and not your route) and a 200 for `foo/app.js`.

Comment: "Should" but that's not happening. Did you try it?