# ASP.NET 4.6 WEB API, Not serving static files(.js, .css) IIS express visual studio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net-4.6

I have been looking over the web and still no luck, hence why I am asking.
I have a WEB API 4.6 project that will also be home to an angularjs2 application,
I have set up to use static files like this:

```
 var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\wwwroot\");
        var options = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            FileSystem = physicalFileSystem,
        };
        var contentTypes = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

        options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = contentTypes;
        options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" };
        options.EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true;
        app.UseFileServer(options);
```

index.html is served, when index.html tries to fetch all the files(.css.js) a 404 error shows up in the console. I have enabled directory browsing and I see that the files are there.

Comment: Just curious! why would you need above code for handling the static files ? The MVC project that I run does have a MVC application, WebAPI endpoints and Angular JS static files. Everything seem to work without above code.

Comment: i am not using mvc, i have a separete project for the angularjs2 and i only want to have a build of it under wwwroot

Answer (score 3):

I found that my code works well, I had to just add the following code to my web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="StaticFile"/>
  <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
</handlers>
```

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294188/using-a-wwwroot-folder-asp-net-5-style-in-asp-net-4-5-project). I believe this could be marked as a duplicate or deleted.

Comment: Are you on Asp.Net 5/ core?

Comment: No, I am using 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using OWIN you can accomplish your goal of serving static files from ~/wwwroot with a web.config setting (URL rewrite) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46857637/1288556).